# Redirecting a domain subfolder to a different IP

Tags: redirect, hosting, subdirectory

I have a client's domain which they currently host on their servers. I want to create a sub-directory and point that to a different IP where part of the site is being hosted.

Their current site is built in ASP.NET and hence the server hosting this would have IIS installed. However, the subfolder site is built in WordPress and is going to be held on a different server hosting Linux.

For example:

www.domain.com is hosted at 188.121.55.128

I would like to have `www.example.com/online` hosted at a different IP: `155.55.123.45`

Is there a way I can do this?

The main site `www.example.com` is built in ASP.NET framework, while the mini pages `www.example.com/online` are built in WordPress.

I do not want to use a subdomain as I would like to take advantage of the fact that the main site has been on Google for many years and in turn has a page rank of 6. If I start with a subdomain the subdomain will have a Page Rank of 0.

Please let me know if there is a way I can map the the subdirectory to a different IP and still have the URL structure in place.

On massive sites, websites are broken into multiple servers and some of these servers are around the world, so I know this is possible however don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In your admin hosting panel (cpanel, plesk or whatever), you should have a "manage domain" section.
In this section find something like "redirect"
There you can configure something like
www.domain.com/online redirect to "http://othersite.com"
and check the option to keep your "www.domain.com/online" URL

Comment: Many thanks for this. However, with this method does Google look at the new site as brand new version or a simple extension of the existing site?

Comment: if you keep the good url, google should only see it as new pages